# 2020 IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate vs Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

As of 2020, are there any features of Android Studio not contained in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate? I know that there are similar questions about that, but they all refer to older versions of both apps.

Let's make the comparison between the newest versions as of 09/22/2020:

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Version 2020.2.2
- Android Studio 4.0.1

Any answer is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/07/intellij-idea-2020-2-is-released/) contains all the Android Studio 4.0 functionality.